# Facebook checkin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code for location

```
function graphlocation(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        var location = response.location.name;
        alert('Post ID: ' + location);
    });
}
```

It gives same location every time I use it even if I change my location in Facebook. I have taken user permissions for checkin.

Any idea what can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

That location is what is set in your user profile under the living section.  That location is static to what you set it to in your profile and not tied to any checkins.  Also perhaps the API is caching your information.  Play around here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to see graph requests in real time.  Mine always updated no matter where I changed my living current city selection to.  What do you get when you check it with the graph API explorer tool?